# Como gerar um resumo ou excerto de cada postagem?

Tags: php, javascript

Estou querendo construir um sistema de postagem php e javascript, eu já sei que o admin vai escrever o post, colocar o assunto, categoria a data vai automático e inserida no banco. Essa parte eu já sei fazer, mas queria saber como eu posso exibir os posts de forma resumida em uma página e quando eu clicar no titulo do post vai carregar uma página própria onde vai ter comentários ( que eu ja sei fazer ) e etc.

```
http://science.tumblr.com/post/116514430985/1-how-to-lewis-structure-it-up-in-here-by
```

O link ficaria dessa forma, por exemplo.

Comment: Você pode ter um campo 'resumo' no banco de dados onde teria um conteúdo diferenciado para exibir como resumo, ou usar a função substrato() do php para recortar uma parte do texto e apresenta-la como preview do post na listagem. Assim o usuário só leria o texto integral ao clicar no título

Comment: Substrato?! Parece que seu corretor aprontou nessa.

Comment: Hahahaha, malditos programadores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma outra solução é limitar por palavras, utilizando explode, assim você não vai deixar uma palavra pela metade.

### Função

```
function limit_words($string, $word_limit, $sus = TRUE, $link = '';) {
    $words = explode(' ',$string);
    return implode(' ',array_splice($words,0,$word_limit)).($sus ? '... <a href="'.$link.'">Leia mais</a>': '');
}
```

### Exemplo de uso

```
$content = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";

echo limit_words($content,20, TRUE, 'https://google.com.br');
```

### Saída

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut... [Leia mais](https://google.com.br)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a função [substr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) (sub string) do php para exibir uma parte do conteúdo. Veja os exemplos de utilização no link da função.

Uma observação interessante é que se o conteúdo possuir html, ele vai contar as tags. Para evitar problemas na exibição você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
//consulta no banco
$semtags = strip_tags($row->conteudo); //remove as tags do php
$resumo = substr($semtags, 0, 255); //pega os primeiros 255 caracteres
```

Comment: Aproveitando pra incrementar a resposta do colega, o conceito é "truncar" o texto, pegando um numero de caracteres. Para ficar mais legal, vale dar um explode na string final usando o espaço como separador, excluir o ultimo elemento, dar um join no array, e adicionar algo como ` [...]` ao final. O efeito é ótimo. :D

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia criar uma coluna 'resumo' na tabela onde ficaria um conteúdo resumido para exibir. Não recomendo usar o substr() pois pode acabar dando spoiler e desinteressando o leitor. Code para exemplificar melhor:

```
try {

    /**
     * 13.2.8 SELECT Syntax
     * https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html
     */
    $stmt = $PDO->query('select * from noticias order by id DESC LIMIT 5');
```

```
/**
 * setting the fetch mode
 * http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php
 */
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

while($row = $stmt->fetch()) { 
    echo ('
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['resume'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['date'].'</td>');}
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira simples é resumir o texto e depois converter para uma url amigável.

```
$texto = "codepad is an online compiler/interpreter, and 
a simple collaboration tool.Paste your code below, and 
codepad will run it and give you a short URL you can use
 to share it in chat or email.";

$resumo  = substr($texto, 0, 30);
$address = strtolower(trim(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/', '-', $resumo), '-'));

echo $address; // codepad-is-an-online-compiler
```

**Exemplo:**
http://codepad.org/1L1wHUDj